# zap weak password and SSL policies

Tags: zap, security-testing

I have search through ZAP documentation and [ZAP Coverage of OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAPpingTheTop10)
and have not determined how to automatically check [weak password policy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_password_policy_(OTG-AUTHN-007)#How_to_Test) and [SSL/TLS testing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SSL-TLS_(OWASP-CM-001)) with ZAP.

Is there a plugin in the ZAP Marketplace?  Is there an approach using ZAP that could be scripted?

I am using an August 2018 weakly release of ZAP.

Answer (score 0):

To "test" the password policy simply use the app and account creation/password change functionality (as outlined in the link you provided). You can do this by creating appropriate Selenium test cases. (It isn't something that ZAP can to automatically.)

For TLS testing you can checkout the HTTPS Info add-on.

Comment: I see the test guidance for the "weak password policy" link under the heading "How to test". How can testing of "weak password policy" (and potentially "SSL/TLS testing") be automated?  (I'll update the question above to reflect 'automation'. )